# Why is fetch sending request to localhost on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, fetch

On server.js I have

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

I think that is the reason requests are going to port 5000, but how can I fix that?

I have an express app which serves a react front end, and makes requests to endpoints on the same domain name.

It's  sending a request to the some_url/auth which I want it to but it's also sending a request to localhost:5000/auth which is causing my application not to work.

Even package.json doesn't have a proxy set to a local host port, so I cannot figure out why GET and POST requests are going to both the localhost/auth and some_url/auth and not only to  some_url/auth.

(client) app.js:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.URL = 'https://reactnote-app.herokuapp.com';
    this.state = {//some stuff}
}

loginRequest = async () => {
    if (!this.state.signup) {
      console.log('login request');
      const endpoint = this.URL +'/auth'
      const res = await
      fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
          'Content-type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify({
          username : document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value,
          password : document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value
        }
      )
      });
      let body = await res.text();
      console.log(body);
      this.getUsername();
    } else {
        this.createUserRequest();
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-notes-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node api/server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "engines":{
    "node":"v12.18.3",
    "npm":"6.14.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us where and how `URL` is defined.

Comment: What is the value of `URL` and then `endpoint` in this `const endpoint = URL +'/auth'`?  I would suggest adding a `console.log(endpoint)` after that statement.

Comment: @Bergi it's defined in the class constructor. Also see my edited post.

Comment: Well show the class constructor.

Comment: @GuyIncognito done. Check edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't run 'npm run build', so it was using the previous build which had URL as localhost.
Works now.